# How do I change the directory that unity is looking in for these files?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I updated my version of the unity editor and I had to delete some old ones to save space on my laptop. Unity keeps giving me this error:

[Image of the error because it won't let me include it for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Wf8.png)

Is there anyway that I can change the directory that it's looking for the missing files in? the folder it's looking for doesn't exist anymore but I should have the files in the new version of unity that I installed.

Comment: Its in the settings where to look for java and sdk etc.

Comment: @BugFinder that's exactly what it was, it was looking it the wrong location for the JDK

Answer (score 0):

Install all android modules when installing the editor from unity hub